# Which holds the electrons stronger: 2p or 3s?

Tags: orbitals

The s orbitals hold electrons stronger than p orbitals, but I do assume this is under the assumption that they are in the same energy levels.

Is there a rule for determining which is stronger between different energy levels, such as between 2p and 3s?

This question was inspired by electronegativity differences between sp2 and sp3 hybrid orbitals (sp2 more electronegative because higher s character)

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts are that 2p holds harder as is on average closer to nucleus.  Regarding hybrid orbitals; sp2 has more of the character of an orbital closer  to nucleus than sp3 coz is likely to be 2s and 3p orbitals. Don't think is much to do with it being spherical.

Answer (score 0):

The orbitals that hold the electrons stronger will populate earlier. Look at noble gases and ions of alkali metals. They don't have 3s electrons, but have 2p electrons. It means that p2 is lower than 3s.

Comparison of different orbitals and different energy levels gets tricky starting with transition metals. It gets even more difficult for actinoids.